# How can I set the value of a JQuery UI Button to something different than the label?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have three inputs like these:

```
<input id="start" type="submit" class="cancel navigation-button" name="Command" value="Start" />
<input id="back" type="submit" class="cancel navigation-button" name="Command" value="Back" />
<input id="next" type="submit" class="cancel navigation-button" name="Command" value="Next" />
```

And then in my javascript I localize the text to the different languages like this:

```
$('#next').button({ label: "@Resources.Next" });
$('#back').button({ label: "@Resources.Back" });
$('#start').button({ label: "@Resources.Start" });
```

The problem is that in my server side code I still expect the value to be "Next", "Back" & "Start". Jquery changes it to the localized text. I just want to change the **label**.

I tried switching to

```
 <button>
```

but then the problem is that I am also using unobtrusive validation and I need to disable it for the "Start" and "Next" buttons. Adding the "cancel" class does that for me, but it only works if I use the input tag.

Any ideas? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can set the labels like this:

```
$('#next').button( "option", "label", "Next" );

$('#back').button( "option", "label", "Back" );

$('#start').button( "option", "label", "Start" );
```

[**API DOCUMENTATION**](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#option-label)

Comment: Yes I did this, the problem is that this also changes the value to be the same as the label. I need the value to be something different than the label.